# VSCode not auto completing HTML

Tags: html, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble with my new installed Visual Studio Code on Windows 7.
On Mac the editor automatically closes html tags but on my Win7 not. I assume there must be some option to turn it on but I can't find any.

I'm talking about when eg. writing `<html` the intelliSense pops up and you click enter, usually it automatically puts in the `</html>` mine's not working.
(The IntelliSense pops up but when you select one of the options it doesn't auto close the tag: `<h1> -> </h1>`)

Comment: 1.you can use **[Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag)** ,it can fullfill your requirement.

Comment: 2.enter a tagname such as **div** ,then enter **tab** key twice ,it will autocomplete the whoe tag ----- >      <div></div>

Comment: you can also create <div> elements with class or id names automatically.
in you editor type .someclassname and press tab. you will get <div class"someclassname"></div>. or just put a # instead of the period and press tab after the name and it will give you a <div> with a id attached.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From the [0.3.0 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_3_0#_html)

> HTML auto closing of tags has now been removed and replaced with smarter IntelliSense on `</`.

Comment: Oh, that's not something I hoped for. Is there any way to bring it back? Modify some files or download something? I'd like to use VSCode but with auto completion. Thanks.

Comment: you can always add a request on their site with uservoice

Comment: Did that, hopefully they bring it back. Thanks for the help. I'm doing Angular development in VSCode. Seems to work well with it so far.

Comment: I was looking for this as well, but I do notice using tab works for me in 0.10.6. E.g. type `div` (without the `<>`) then press tab straight away, and it enters `<div></div>`. Not exactly the same, but may be of use. Doco for these shortcuts (emmet) [here](http://docs.emmet.io)

Comment: yes, that is due to Emmet. Emmet let's us type element names without the braces and it will add what is needed. It's really powerful.

Comment: This does not work for me on VS Code 1.5.3. If I type <div> then </ it does not close / complete the tag. Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Just typing `div` without `<>` and then pressing tab doesn't work anymore after the latest updates. Is there a way to re-enable this?

Comment: @peterc that by itself should be an answer. thats so useful

Answer (score 216):

Type the tag name (without starting `<`) then press Tab

for example type `div` then press tab and VS will convert it to `<div></div>`

Or type the opening tag then press Tab twice

for example :

1. type `<div`
2. press Tab
3. press Tab

it will add the closing tag

Comment: What about self closing tags (e.g. <input />)?

Comment: just type input and press Tab twice, VS Code will auto complete it to <input type="text">

Comment: Just want to add that this is part of Emmet functionality, which allows you to easily generate more complex HTML structure, not only tag pairs. For examples you can read [this](https://designshack.net/articles/css/7-awesome-emmet-html-time-saving-tips/), or just google for Emmet.

Comment: @Rabolf can you mention some other cool HMTL shortcuts for VS Code?

Comment: @eMAD unfortunately I did not continue using VS Code

Comment: First suggestion works excellently - thanks! Second suggestion doesn't really work anymore, as you end up with `<<div></div>` after the first tab. So just continue typing `div` and then Tab :)

Comment: It works perfectly ! No need of installing extensions ! But the thing is you have to change your habit while using other editors.

Comment: It is not working for me. Is there anything else I need to check?

Comment: The answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53877217/539883) solved it for me. I am editing a .HTML file but VS Code was in the language mode for Nunjucks.

Comment: Thank you. That was the quickest and most helpful answer I've had to a question in ages. I was adding the opening bracket which kills the autocomplete.

Answer (score 210):

I was experiencing the same problem, then i saw something on my bottom right of vs code.. instead of using HTML, i was using Django-HTML, so i changed the language to html, Boom everything is working fine again.[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpE7P.png)

Comment: Had a similar problem, but in my case I realised I was writing HTML into a PHP file. Suppose I won't be able to make use of autoclosing tags for as long as I am.

Comment: is not necesary to change language, only add to settings.json     "emmet.includeLanguages": { "django-html": "html"}

Comment: I fixed my Twig templates not intellisensing HTML thanks to @raultedesco comment above. `Ctrl+Shift+p` -> open `Perferences: Open Settings (UI)` -> search for `includedLanguages` -> found Emmet Included Languages -> input `Item: twig; Value: html` -> press `Add item` -> enjoy.

Comment: You just saved me, I've been stuck with these for months, until I had the time today of looking into it, I was totally going to reinstall vs and start again when I came into your answer. Awesome.

Comment: Mine was on a go html template. This saved me a bunch of time. Thanks!

Comment: I had this same issue too, checked the screenshot you sent and I was able to resolve mine the same way. I was using django_html too instead of html, thanks

Comment: I have writing Django, so the problem you mentioned happens. This works for me.

Comment: Thanks @Siphamandla Ngwenya. How can I get both HTML and Django features in a file ?

Answer (score 32):

Here is a cool trick *(actually an Emmet abbreviation)* :

- write the tag name ­ **|** e.g. **`h1`**
- add an asterisk after that ­ **|** e.g. **`h1*`**
- press <kbd>Tab</kbd> ­ **|** (will result in `<h1></h1>`)

­

<sub>**PS:** This also works for self-closing tags, such as - `input` , `img` etc.</sub>

Comment: @Kokodoko Yes it **does** `:P`

Comment: That's so weird..... I'm not sure what setting to change to re-enable it...

Comment: @Kokodoko you should have the emmet extension installed.

Comment: This works, but there's no need to include the `*`. 1.21.0

Comment: this doesn't work. @Sudhanshu there are thousands of extensions with the name emmet

Comment: @BlueClouds yes and any of them that provides html abbreviation support, should work. By a generic rule, I use the one with max installs.

Comment: No asterisk required here in Nov.2019. just tag name and tab is enough

Answer (score 23):

Change from Django-html to html .[image]

Answer (score 19):

1. Press **Ctrl + Shift + P** to open the command palette.
2. Type **'Change Language Mode'** in the searcher.
3. Select **'Change Language Mode'**.
4. Type **'HTML'** in the searcher.
5. And select **'HTML'** (it was probably set to 'django-html)

Answer (score 9):

I've encountered same problem on Mac Sierra (10.12.6) with VSCode (1.30.2), while editing an HTML file. According to the vscode documentations https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html, the intellisense should work out of box.

Turned out that the "Language Detection" (on the right corner of editor status bar at the bottom of screen) is set to Automatic Detection, and recognized the file as `django-html`. When manually switched back to plain Html, everything works.

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>++</kbd> --> type in    --> then select

It works for me.

Comment: I don't see anything new in this answer

Comment: @Vega I think this is still helpful for the new VSCode user like me.

Comment: Have you checked that this is not be already said in other answers?

Answer (score 5):

1. List item Goto Settings: File -> Preferences -> Settings (CTRL + COMMA shortkey in Ubuntu).
2. In Search Bar type **Emmet**.
3. Find **Trigger Expansion On Tab** and check it.

Comment: Thank you... Who knew that this would be a problem in this day and age. The folding stopped working in the `<script>` in the most recent update.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep "Django HTML" as the file language and still have auto-closing tags, just add the following to `settings.json` (provided you have the `auto close tag` extension installed):

```
  "auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
    "django-html",
    (...other languages if needed)
  ],
```

Answer (score 2):

File > Preferences > Keymaps, 
Search 'Auto close' and click on install.
If it doesn't work, reload the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open the command.
Then, type `Change Language Mode` an select `HTML` or any other desired language.

Answer (score 2):

If you type

> div.class

and then press **TAB**, VS code will automatically close the **DIV** tag with the given **CLASS**

But I think you want to do this operation by pressing the **ENTER** key.

In that case, go to your VS Code user setting & paste the following code:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact",
    "vue-html": "html",
    "razor": "html",
    "plaintext": "jade"
}
```

Now if you type

> div.class

& then press the **ENTER** key, you can see the magic.

However, the above code will make your VS Code auto-completion with **ENTER** key not only for normal **HTML** but also the **JSX of React**, **Vue.js snippets** will also cover by this.

But If you want to do it only for HTML file, just the following line is enough:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "html" }
```

Cheers..

Answer (score 2):

If HTML tags autocompleting issue is on JavaScript files, then you just need to change "select language mode" from "JavaScript" to "JavaScript React".

Answer (score 1):

I was suffering from the  same problem,then  I uninstalled unnecessary extensions from VS Code along with JavaScript (SE) extension and it  worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the bottom of your vscode and change the language mode to HTML
It might have been showing django-html
or click ctrl + shift + p to change the language mode
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16gbj.png)

Now click [!] + TAB
voila it's done!!!

Answer (score 0):

Goto Settings `cmd+,`

find `Emmet: Included Languages` add

add Item `django-html` Value `html`

[image: django-html]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying in a `JavaScript` try to change the language in bottom of the VSCode to `JavaScript JSX`:

[image]

It resolved my issue.