# VS Code HTML mode option to turn off auto close tags

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I cannot figure out the option to turn off the new "feature" where the VS Code HTML mode editor types stuff for you in the following scenario:

I type `<b>` and when I hit that last `>` it then types `</b>` which I then have to delete and move to where I want it.

How do I keep VS Code from typing stuff for me in this case? I have these two options set like this:

```json
"editor.quickSuggestions": false,
"editor.autoClosingBrackets": false,
```

> Sort of the opposite of this question: [VSCode not auto completing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696863/vscode-not-auto-completing-html#37638626)

Answer (score 19):

I found it:

```
// Enable/disable autoclosing of HTML tags.
"html.autoClosingTags": true,
```

This new feature shipped with `autoClosingTags` set to `true` by default, which was, unfortunately, a disruptive change if you were used to being able to type without random stuff being inserted into your document as a side effect.

Setting `autoClosingTags` to `false` restores the original behavior.

```
"html.autoClosingTags": true,
```

Comment: Hi Jared, where is this configuration file for VS?

Comment: @Eralper -  The location of settings file of VS Code on windows is %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json

Comment: Sorry ekhanna, it did not help. I installed VS2019 preview on Win10. Checked Program Files including ProgramData in addition to AppData folders

Comment: Thanks for this. Have been running into the same frustration. I searched for `html.autoClosingTags` in the settings search and it appeared.

Answer (score 0):

```
"html.autoClosingTags": true,
```

Does not work for me .. maybe misleading or bug
I do a workaround to change the type of the file down the editor to handlebars or another language because it was very frustrating for me that the editor insists to add something I understand I do not need like closing  tag while the closing tag should be at footer file.