# Visual Studio Code Not Auto-Close Tags in HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, auto-close

So version before 1.30 worked fine, and did close the Tags in .html file, but as of 1.30 update I can't finish  and then try to close it with

I have tried to delete config.json file, also tried to turno on every possible option for auto-close and auto-complete tags in options, but nothing worked.

And Sublime it's working fine. I downloaded plugin to transfer Sublime confing into Visual Studio Code  but without success. Hope you can help me out, since i've been trying to fix this problem 3 hours now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode not auto completing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696863/vscode-not-auto-completing-html)

Comment: @BenTegoni I wonder if an answer from 2015 regarding version 0.3.0 can explain the change in the behaviour of version 1.3.0 in 2018. I don't know the answer but I am curious if you can really say that this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I noticed that my select language mode was something like Django HTML. Solved after changing it.

Answer (score 0):

You might have opened a file before that changed the language mode. So first, check the language shown at the bottom-right of the VS Code window (status bar), then follow the steps bellow.

Go to settings (or edit the `settins.json` file) and search `emmet.includeLanguages`, then press `add item` under Emmet: Include Languages. input the language you are using in item field and `html` in value field.