# VSCode HTML How to enable autoclose tag and tag suggestions

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In my VSCode, when I'm using html when I put new tags it doesn't give me a suggestion of tag names. Also, how to autoclose a tag with > when I'm writing? I have HTML Snippets, Boiler, Intellisense Auto Complete Tag extensions installed already.

Here is what is written in setting.json

```
"python.pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3",
"editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary",
"editor.tabCompletion": "on",

"auto-close-tag.enableAutoCloseTag": true,
"auto-close-tag.fullMode": true,
"auto-close-tag.SublimeText3Mode": true,
"html.format.indentInnerHtml": true,
"html.format.endWithNewline": true,
"html-css-class-completion.enableEmmetSupport": true,
"html.suggest.html5": true
```

Comment: BTW, you can use Emmet and you just type for example `div`, press Tab and you get a `<div></div>`. There's also some cool stuff that comes with it, for example you can make an entire table with some lorem ipsum text inside in one line. Emmet is built-in to VS Code so you don't have to install anything

Comment: It's not giving suggestions on something as simple as body and div though (for div it reccomends divisibleby instead).  Also pressing tab don't work for getting <div></div>

Comment: Yeah probably for div you just use `.class` and it will make a `<div class="class"></div>`. Also other extensions might take priority over Emmet.

Answer (score 2):

I just found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696863/vscode-not-auto-completing-html), third answer down.  It turns out VS Code was auto detecting the language as "django-html" instead of vanilla "html", and as a result, none of the extensions I'd been installing on VS Code for html were working!

You can change the auto detect to regular HTML by clicking in the bottom right of VS Code where it says django-html and changing it to regular html.