# VS Code isn't recognizing html files

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

VS had suddenly stopped recognizing HTML files and it doesn't autocomplete tags or even show the syntax unless I manually input every single file name in it, I would really appreciate the help on any idea how to solve that [Here is how it looks:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp1cO.png)

I have tried many things but nothing seems to work or help fix it

Comment: may be useful in your case please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696863/vscode-not-auto-completing-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solves the problem:
On the bottom right of the application, you should see something like this:[image: bar]

Click on the "Plain text".

[image: search]

Search HTML in the list and click it.

Then your HTML should turn colorful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer!
I didn't have the small bar on the bottom right but I was able to get to it by opening the file and pressing `Ctrl + Shift + P` and it seemed that I had to do that for every file and it would go back to being not colorful (Not recognized by VS code that its HTML file) when I close and re-open VS code but I was able to solve it by: 

`CTRL + Shift + P` -> "Change Language Mode" -> "Configure File Association for ".html"" -> "HTML"

and that solved it for what it seems like permanently so thank you!